# Play sounds in a firefox extension

Tags: firefox, audio, firefox-addon, xul

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Playing a sound in a Firefox add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596466/playing-a-sound-in-a-firefox-add-on)

I am building a firefox extension, and I need to play a sound file (local) when a button is clicked.

I am new to extension development and have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You use the HTML5 `<audio>` tag. E.g. if you have a XUL document you add it like this:

```html
<audio xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="clickSound" src="click.ogg" />
```

When you need to play the sound you do:

```js
document.getElementById("clickSound").play();
```

In other words, it's exactly the same [as in a web page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video). Only that you have to specify the XHTML namespace if you are in a XUL document.