# Firefox SDK: correct way to play audio from the url in 2015 year?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to add ability to my addon to play audio from URL. At [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=play%20audio&topic=addons&page=2) I not found information about this. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449813/play-audio-from-firefox-extensions-data-directory) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292504/firefox-addon-sdk-not-playing-audio-using-new-audio#_=_) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596466/playing-a-sound-in-a-firefox-add-on) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661507/how-to-play-audio-in-an-extension) answers - but this is about local file and what the correct answer for 2015 year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Noitidart Future is coming and at 2015 you can write much less code!

```
var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
var audio = new window.Audio('http://example.com/audio.mp3');
audio.play();
```

Comment: Very very nice!! :) Does it work with local files too? (`file:///`)? I don't understand this line `var audio = ('http://example.com/audio.mp3');` thats just a string

Comment: Sorry yes second line was incorrect - now is ok. I don't know about local files - you can check and write comment here with your result :)

Comment: I don thave the sdk environment, would it be too hard to change the uri to a file uri as a test? I do so much for people cant people do a little for me? :P

Comment: @Noitidart I tryed in debug `new window.Audio('file:///home/vitaly/Desktop/audio.mp3').play()` and I hear the music - it's work :)

Comment: Thanks! :) That's awesome news!

Answer (score 2):

I have an answer from 2016 ;)

That code will not work with Multi-process Firefox (will be released in 2016):

```
var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
var audio = new window.Audio('http://example.com/audio.mp3');
vaudio.play();
```

Because `sdk/window/utils`. To understand why read this [topic on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Working_with_multiprocess_Firefox).

Solution is `page-worker`:

**main.js:**

```
var pageWorkers = require("sdk/page-worker");
var audioWorker = pageWorkers.Page({
    contentURL: './blank.html', //blank html file in `data` directory
    contentScriptFile: './worker.js'
});

// for example i want to play song from url
var url = 'http://some-url.com/some-song.mp3';
// send msg to worker to play this url
audioWorker.port.emit('play', url);
```

**worker.js**

```
var audio = new window.Audio;

self.port.on('play', function(url) {
    audio.src = url;
    audio.play();
});
```

It works in my extension and will work with new Multi-process Firefox release.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me Im not sure how 2015 it is, but i wrote like a couple months ago:

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

function audioContextCheck() {
    if (typeof Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.AudioContext !== 'undefined') {
        return new Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.AudioContext();
    } else if (typeof Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.mozAudioContext !== 'undefined') {
        return new Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.mozAudioContext();
    } else {
        throw new Error('AudioContext not supported');
    }
}

var audioContext = audioContextCheck();

var audioBuffer;

var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest();
getSound.open('get', OS.Path.toFileURI(OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, 'zirzir.mp3')), true);
getSound.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
getSound.onload = function() {
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(getSound.response, function(buffer) {
        audioBuffer = buffer;
        var playSound = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        playSound.buffer = audioBuffer;
        playSound.connect(audioContext.destination);
        playSound.start(audioContext.currentTime);
    });
};
```

Comment: I am getting `XMLHttpRequest is not defined`