# Running a HTML5 Audio player in a Firefox Add-ons SDK page-worker

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, html5-video, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to repair a firefox addon that I created some time ago which has stopped functioning properly after a recent-ish Firefox update. The part which no longer functions was a mp3 player, which ran in the background.

The [page-worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker) has a very small html page with an embedded media player and a script that controls the player. The script is passed in a filepath for an mp3 on my machine to use as the players src, and then told to start playing. This used to work, but now upon calling the embedded player's play function an error is thrown. The src is correctly set and the play event triggers, but the canplay event does not. The error code given is 4, which I believe is MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED.

If I open the HTML page and feed the player the filepath manually, it all works fine. What's going wrong here that wasn't before?

The HTML page is

```
<!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sound Stone: mp3 pageworker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video></video>
    </body>
<html>
```

The content script is

```
var player = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

var starttime;
var stoptime;

var checkTime;

self.port.on("start", function(url){
    player.src=url;
    player.pause();
    stoptime = undefined;
    self.port.emit("change", false);
});

self.port.on("stop", function(){
    player.pause();
    player.removeEventListener("canplay", goTo);
});

self.port.on("play", function(beg, end){
    clearInterval(checkTime);
    if(beg){
        starttime = beg/1000;
    }
    if(end){
        stoptime = end/1000;
    }
    player.play(); // this is where it goes wrong
    if(beg){
        player.addEventListener("canplay", goTo);
    }
    if(stoptime){
        checkTime = setInterval(function (){
            if(player.currentTime>=stoptime){
                player.currentTime=99999;
                clearInterval(checkTime);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
});

self.port.on("pause", function(){
    player.pause();
});

player.onplay = function(){
    self.port.emit("change", true);
}

player.onpause = function(){
    self.port.emit("change", false);
}

player.onended = function(){
    self.port.emit("done");
}

player.onerror = function(){
    self.port.emit("out", player.error.code); // this outputs 4
    self.port.emit("out", player.src); // this outputs as expected
}

function goTo(){
    player.currentTime=starttime;
    player.removeEventListener("canplay", goTo);
}
```

And a small excerpt of the main program is

```
var mp3 = worker.Page({
    contentScriptFile: "./mp3.js",
    contentURL: "./mp3.html",
});

mp3.port.on("out", function(msg){ 
    console.log(msg);
});
```

Comment: This user here did the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755863/firefox-sdk-correct-way-to-play-audio-from-the-url-in-2015-year/32758945#32758945

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Still interested in why this no longer works though.

Comment: If you find out please do share :)